# Is time within a range? Always returns false

Tags: php

I have written this simple PHP code to tell me whether the current time has passed and whether it is less than 6am.

The current time is 17:56, but this code echos "no".
What is going wrong?

```
$hourMin = date('H:i');
if ($hourMin >= strtotime('17:00') && $hourMin <= strtotime('06:00')) {
  echo "Yes";
} else {
  echo "No";
}
```

Comment: strtotime() returns a timestamp, date('H:i') returns string "14:11" (for example). You can't compare this.

Comment: you will probably benefit from using the [PHP DateTime object](https://paulund.co.uk/datetime-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic problem. How can can something be greater than 17:00 hours and also subsequently less than 06:00 hours? That is why it will always print no.

You have essentially created `if (1==0) { echo "Yes" }` Surely you see that will never ever happen.

**EDIT:**

You also need to wrap `$hourMin` in `strtotime`

```
if (strtotime($hourMin) >= strtotime('17:00') || 
    strtotime($hourMin) <= strtotime('06:00')) {
```

Comment: Ok that makes sence im trying to work out whether the current time is greater than 5pm and less than 6am thought this would be a straight forward one lol

Comment: I think what you want is the or operator here... change the `&&` to `||`

Comment: Check whether it's >= 17:00 or <= 06:00

Comment: this will be to change a var eventually if the current time is greater than 5pm and less than 6am

Comment: tried changing it to || for or but still doesnt work as intended

Comment: *still doesn't work as intended* Can you elaborate? Changing to the `OR` operator would do what your question asks.

Comment: Please see my edit. I didn't realize you weren't comparing the same thing. @Macie Schmidt pointed out, you need to compare the same things.

Comment: Ok perhaps i cant explain it that well, the script should display yes if the current time is after 5pm and before 6am but it its after 6am and before 5pm then it will echo no. Hope this makes more sense thanks guys for helping

Comment: Thanks Martin and Mituw16 amazing that did it working a treat now, awesome guys thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)